# Robot framework: Extent image compare function

Tags: python, robotframework

I've writen my own image compare function for RobotFramework with the help of a question asked over here.

```
from PIL import Image, ImageChops, ImageDraw, ImageFont
def check_image_files(self, file1, file2, file3)                :
    ''' Check two image files

    ``file1``: absolute path to the first file

    ``file2``: absolute path to the second file

    ``file3``: absolute path to the compare file
    '''

    self.builtin.log("File1: %s" %file1)
    self.builtin.log("File2: %s" %file2)

    point_table = ([0] + ([255] * 255))

    f1 = Image.open(file1)
    f2 = Image.open(file2)

    diff = ImageChops.difference(f1, f2)
    diff = diff.convert('L')
    diff = diff.point(point_table)
    f3 = diff.convert('RGB')
    f3.paste(f2, mask=diff)        
    f3.save(file3)
```

The end result now is a complete black screen if there are  no differences found in the file, but I want to get a true / false back. So I can let the testcase PASS / FAIL if the 2 files are not identical. Now the testcase succeeds if the files are not identical for a small part and that's not what I want.

I've read the PIL documentation but couldnt get what I needed (btw I'm a tester with a interest for Programming)

Comment: http://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.4.x/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.getbbox "If the image is completely empty, this method returns None" get the bounding box and if it's `None` you have a match in the images

Answer (score 0):

The below example is from the RossetaCode.org on [basic image comparison](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Percentage_difference_between_images#Python) where they calculate the difference. This is of course a precursor to determining if an image is identical or not. In case it is, then 0,0 is returned.

```
from itertools import izip
from PIL import Image

i1 = Image.open("image1.png")
i2 = Image.open("image2.png")
assert i1.mode == i2.mode, "Different kinds of images."
assert i1.size == i2.size, "Different sizes."

pairs = izip(i1.getdata(), i2.getdata())
if len(i1.getbands()) == 1:
    # for gray-scale jpegs
    dif = sum(abs(p1-p2) for p1,p2 in pairs)
else:
    dif = sum(abs(c1-c2) for p1,p2 in pairs for c1,c2 in zip(p1,p2))

ncomponents = i1.size[0] * i1.size[1] * 3
print "Difference (percentage):", (dif / 255.0 * 100) / ncomponents
```